# Is there any performance impact of using too many font-face declarations?

Tags: css, browser, fonts, cross-browser, font-face

**Question:**

If there is a big list of font-faces in a CSS file (say over 2000), how efficiently browser will pick a font from the "big list" for application to an HTML block? **Please ignore font file size, network latency, caching or everything else.**

**Details:**

I am working on an opensource project to create a single CSS file that contains font-faces of all fonts hosted on fonts.google.com. The reason is to make font inclusion simple and cross project, i.e just include the same single CSS file in every project, and lets go.

I am concerned about performance impact of too many font-face declarations. The overall CSS file size will be less than 25KB Gzipped, so I am ok with that. But there will be 1950+ font-faces that can potentially make some browsers slow in real world.

Although these font files **will not be downloaded** by browsers unless they are really used in the HTML document, so thats not an issue. I am just concerned about browsers' efficiency of handling these font-faces declarations in memory and efficiently referencing to them when used in CSS.

Can anyone help?

**Edit:**

Here is the css file that I plan to use: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/praisedpk/Local-Google-Fonts/master/google-fonts/webfonts.css

Its from github repo: [Local Google Fonts](https://github.com/praisedpk/Local-Google-Fonts)

Comment: Uhh, no? that's not how CSS works - these fonts **will** all be downloaded, even if the web page does not use them: a CSS engine will **always** download a font indicated by a `@font-face` declaration, possibly multiple times if you specify multiple sources and the first (few) fail to pass sanitization. Unless you are doing some kind of JavaScript based selective loading based on client-side detection, you just wrote an insane stylesheet that should never, ever, be used.

Comment: Its not like this I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726928/will-a-browser-download-a-font-face-even-if-it-is-not-used-in-the-page and http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67073/performance-hit-of-a-lot-of-unused-font-faces

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: cheers, I'm going to have to dig through the spec again and see what the technical requirements were here.

Comment: I suggest adding the SO tag of "caching" to your question since that appears to be the main concern of the issue that you are inquiring about.

Comment: @JohnH did you read the question? 3 of 4 answers below seem to be written without even reading the question in detail. I am not concerned about caching or "all fonts will be downloaded" sort of issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're not asking for network loading times but rather for the time to select the right font declaration from the loaded list.

The time to select the font from the css file is neglectable. Almost any other operation while loading your site will take much more time. If you'd like to test this with your browser of choice, just open the [css file in the browser](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/praisedpk/Local-Google-Fonts/master/google-fonts/webfonts.css) and search for any font with `CTRL+F`. The results should be visible in less than 100ms, even on older machines.

Anyway you should consider that not all browsers behave the same and that Internet Explorer (or at least the older versions) WILL download every font you declare. It doesn't matter if you use it or not so your project won't be an option if the site should be cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Yes exactly, I am concerned about this. But can we really compare CSS parsing and font selecting with simple text search? Is there a way to benchmark this?

Comment: @HamidSarfraz you could benchmark it by changing fonts via JavaScript and track the time it takes to do so. Then try the same with a site having much less font declarations and compare the results (host it locally so you don't have network delay).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a performance impact, but it is not terribly high.

To measure the impact, I used Chrome's "**Inspect**" option with the "**Network**" tab.
(Other options are available to do this too.)

I went to the link provided after checking the "**Disable cache**" button. Doing so enables you to measure the full impact of downloading a file for the first time.

This shows that the webfonts.css file is 17.9 KB in size and took my system using Chrome to download it in 26ms. (Not too bad, but this all depends on what is good enough in your judgement.)

[image]

If you hover over the "Waterfall" time bar you can see more details about this file download to the browser.

[image]

Comment: Thanks sir for the answer. My main concern is: How efficiently browser will pick a font from the big list of around 2000 font-faces for application to an HTML block?

Comment: I have edited the question to put more focus on my concern. Please check.

Answer (score 3):

You have to consider two perspectives: The network and the rendering of the browser. Both aspects cause performance impacts when you load a lot of fonts. Google has the same problems on https://fonts.google.com/ - and they have solved it quite well.

So let's see what they have done. Let's open Chrome, open https://fonts.google.com/, press F12 to open the developer tools and press F5 to relead the page. Now switch to the network tab to see which files have been loaded. Surprise: only about 25 fonts have been loaded.

Now scroll down the page to see more font samples - and watch the network tab. You will see that Google loads more and more fonts while you scroll down.
This is called "loading on demand". See this SO topic for more information: [Load fonts on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144937/load-fonts-on-demand)

```
var link = document.createElement("link")
link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
link.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
link.setAttribute("href", "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower")
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link)
```

So Google watches which parts of the page are currently visible and loads the fonts immediatly. Of course they also apply caching headers to make this process faster when a user revisits the website.

To detect if a certain part of your site is in view you can use scripts like this one: https://plnkr.co/edit/91gybbZ7sYVELEYvy1IK?p=preview

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  myElement = $('.someObject');
  window.onscroll = function() {

    var screenTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var screenBottom = screenTop + $(window).height();    
    var elTop = $(myElement).offset().top;
    var elBottom = elTop + $(myElement).height();

    var info = 'screenTop:' + screenTop + ' screenBottom:' + screenBottom + ' elTop:' + elTop + ' elBottom:' + elBottom;

    if((elBottom <= screenBottom) && (elTop >= screenTop)) {
      $('.info').html('Element is in view + <small>' + info + '</small>');
    } else {
      $('.info').html('Element is out of view + <small>' + info + '</small>');
    }

  }
})
```

Comment: Sir, I am not going to use all the fonts. I am not concerned about the caching either. Please see this answer above: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42978299/369005 and my comment on the answer.

Comment: If the answer from "loafer" is "exactly" what you were looking for, then please mark that answer as accepted so that he can get the +50 bounty.

Comment: You are NOT going to use all the fonts?? You were writing: "huge list of fonts" ... "a single CSS file that contains font-faces of all fonts hosted on fonts.google.com." Loading on demand will solve every issue you were writing about.

Comment: loafer's did not exactly answer what I am asking. @Gerfried I am not going to use all the fonts that will be in the font list. My objective is to use single CSS fonts file on all my projects, but use only one or two fonts per project. I am concerned about performance of browser's selection of font from long list of font-face declarations, and then speed of rendering text in that font.

Answer (score 1):

Use cache-control settings in the response header of your posted pages to inform the browser how long a cached CSS file can be reused before checking for a newer version.

For example, using the SO website and viewing a downloaded CSS file with Chrome's **Inspect** function, a max-age value of 604,800 seconds (1 week) is defined.

[image]

To show a display like the prior image, click on a file listed in the "**Network**" tab of Chrome's **Inspect** utility.

I believe that the max-age duration informs the browser how long it can use the currently cached file before it needs to check to see if a newer file is available. In some instances, it is better to have this duration be much shorter.

For more information about this, visit this [MDN page on Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control).

There are also numerous SO entries with the **cache-control** topic that may be applicable to your website's environment.

Comment: Sir, I am not going to use all the fonts. I am not concerned about the caching either. Please see this answer above: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42978299/369005 and my comment on the answer.